# Sampling point from the surface of an n-dimensional ellipsoid with uniform distribution

Tags: random-walks, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-mechanics

I am wondering if exist an efficient computational  method for sampling points belonging to the surface of an ellipsoid in $n$-dimensional space with n even, I am thinking in the phase space of a system with $f$-degrees of freedom that have dimensionality $2f,$ the aim is picking phase-space  points that have the same total energy. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: OK, perhaps thinking in a phase space states with energy $E = T(p) +V(q),$ one can pick at random $q$ which energy is less or equal than $E,$ if the energy is less than $E$ the remaining momentum can be picked from the  ball $T(p)=cte$. But this is not a satisfactory answer to the question I did. Is this approach correct? How to do it efficiently using a computer?

Comment: The problem easily reduces to sampling from the surface of the unit sphere. For this, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/

Comment: @SteveHuntsman: May I ask, what is the reduction?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Determine an affine transformation mapping the sphere to the ellipsoid. Then sample uniformly from the sphere and apply the aforementioned affine transformation. By linearity (perhaps I should say affinity?), this yields a uniform sample from the ellipsoid.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman from the solid ellipsoid, yes, from the surface, no.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman: Igor's [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/982833/237) seems to imply that a linear map distorts and must be corrected.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I stand corrected! It is sort of funny that my original comment holds if the word "easily" is removed though.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman: :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ellipsoid is not too squashed, the method described in the first answer to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973101/how-to-generate-points-uniformly-distributed-on-the-surface-of-an-ellipsoid) should work decently. If it *IS* very squashed, it won't, but an ellispoid with $a \gg b > c> \dots $ is essentially a product of a lower dimensional ellipsoid with an interval, so you can reduce the problem to a lower dimensional one (with some (slight) loss of uniformity.)